# How to add pdf/byte[] messge reader to exchangeStrategies, Content type 'application/pdf' not supported

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

i can't make a valid consumption of pdf rest web service using webClient (webflux)

here is my webClient creation :

```
ExchangeStrategies pdfExchangeStrategy = ExchangeStrategies
                        .builder()
                        .codecs(
                                        clientCodecConfigurer -> {
                                            CustomCodecs customCodecs = clientCodecConfigurer.customCodecs();
                                            final ByteArrayDecoder byteArrayDecoder = new ByteArrayDecoder(){

                                                @Override
                                                public List<MimeType> getDecodableMimeTypes() {
                                                    return Collections.singletonList(APPLICATION_PDF);
                                                }
                                            };
                                            customCodecs.decoder(byteArrayDecoder);
                                            customCodecs.encoder(new ByteArrayEncoder());
                                            DecoderHttpMessageReader pdfReader = new DecoderHttpMessageReader(byteArrayDecoder);
                                            customCodecs.reader(pdfReader);
                                        }
                        )
                        .build();
        this.webClient = webClientFactory
                        .newBuilder(logger, "My web client")
                        .exchangeStrategies(pdfExchangeStrategy)
                        .defaultHeader(ACCEPT, APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
                        .defaultHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
                        .baseUrl(this.baseUrl)
                        .build();
```

and here is my call :

```
webClient.get()
                 .uri("http://localhost:8084/my-app/document/{id}", id)
                 .accept(APPLICATION_PDF)
                 .retrieve()
                 .bodyToMono(Byte[].class)
                 .block();
```

i get this error :

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'application/pdf' not supported
```

even though in supportedMediaTypes, i have application/pdf

the consumed web service is :

```
@GetMapping(value = "/document/{id}", produces = APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getDocument(@PathVariable String id) throws IOException {
        LOGGER.info("get  document with id =  {}", id);
        byte[] pdf = getInvoicePdf("document/sample.pdf");
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData("filename",  id + ".pdf");
        headers.setContentType(APPLICATION_PDF);
        headers.setContentLength(pdf.length);
        return ResponseEntity
                        .ok()
                        .headers(headers)
                        .body(pdf);
    }
```

thanks for your help

Comment: just by changing my call to as follow, it works:

 webClient.get()
           .uri("http://localhost:8084/my-app/document/{id}", id)
           .accept(APPLICATION_PDF)
           .exchange()
           .doOnSuccess(
             errorConsumer
           )
           .block()
           .bodyToMono(byte[].class)
           .block();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally no need to all that boilerplate exchangeStrategies, all is needed to solve this probleme is :

```
        webClient.get()
                 .uri("http://localhost:8084/my-app/document/{id}", id)
                 .accept(APPLICATION_PDF)
                 .exchange()
                 .block()
                 .bodyToMono(byte[].class)
                 .block()
```